# Is the result of Fourier transform always complex?

Tags: fourier-transform

Is the result of Fourier transform always complex?I mean, no matter the signal,$g(t)$, is real or image.In my opinion,i think the answer is "No",because fourier transform is $$ G(f)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} g(t)*e^{-j2\pi ft}dt $$ 
If $g(t)$ is $e^{j2\pi ft}$ ,complex and even ,then $G(f)$ is not complex.So if the $g(t)$ is complex ,$G(f)$ must not complex,and if the signal is real or image,$G(f)$ must be complex,is my opinion right?

Comment: If $g(t)$ is Hermittian then $G(f)$ is always real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed functions for which th Fourier transform is only real valued. The most prominent example would be the Gaussian function
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \alpha \exp(-\beta x^2).
\end{align*}
The important fact here is that $f$ is symmetric around $0$.
In the Wikipedia article on Characteristic Functions (another name for Fourier transforms in probability theory) you can find more information and examples:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)